# Manage Add-Ins page blank

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When going to Manage Add-ins in OWA, we would get a blank page.  We found very little information on it, but finally this article below which solved our issue.  The basic premise is to move the arbitration mailboxes to latest version of Exchange.  We had arbitration mailboxes on 3 different versions of Exchange.

https://supertekboy.com/2018/05/18/there-was-a-problem-loading-your-options/

Just want to know what is the role of arbitration mailbox in Manage Add-ins, and if we just missed this step as a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found a solution to your problem. There's an [article here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt441791(v=exchg.150).aspx) on how to move the system mailboxes (also called arbitration mailboxes). For migration best practices, I don't have a particular article to recommend, but looking for articles that include this step, I see it in a [few](http://windowstechpro.com/part-6-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2016-migration-mailboxes-move/) [places](http://markgossa.blogspot.com/2015/12/exchange-2013-to-2016-migration-part-4.html).

As mentioned in the first article, system mailboxes are "used to store organization-wide data." For add-ins, this includes configuration for organization add-ins installed by an administrator. These add-ins appear on a user's manage add-ins page along with any user-installed add-ins.